# Flutter : Card with Gridview

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout

I'm New to flutter I want to make this design , it take me awhile to find what to use , but ever time i try to code it and use Listview it give me error ,or the card dont aligns to Gridview.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.refer `GridView`  [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)

```
   Center(
              child: GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                itemCount: 4,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                  return Card(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 290,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Image.network(
                                  'https://tech.pelmorex.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/flutter.png',
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Title',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    'Subtitle',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 0.0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                  mainAxisExtent: 264,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Your result screen-> [image: output]

Answer (score -2):

You can use Gridview and return a Card of your custom style in Gridview Builder I will build your Required Design.

Here is the GridView Official Documentation.
[Documentation[1](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)